C# Datagridview: Multiple Selected Change All Values in First Selected Row
I have Excel data. I import this data into C# datagridview. Datagridview rows selected by users need to be merged.
Data&Output Sample:
https://imgur.com/a/WrJAkwN
The data in some columns will remain the same and the data in some columns will be merged.
Sample images will be enlightening.
I try MultiSelet & SelectedRows. I can't pull the data correctly.
I need methods or viewpoint.
